# Meaning of "Il demande le numéro à Chantal."

Tags: sens, prépositions

There appears to be two translations :

- 1. He asks for Chantal's number.
- 2. He asks Chantal for the number.

Isn't "Chantal" the direct object and therefore doesn't need **à** ?

Comment: In fact, the "**c**omplément d'**o**bjet **d**irect" is "le numéro", and the "**c**omplément d'**o**bjet **i**ndirect" is "Chantal". **C.O.D.**: Il demande quoi ? Le numéro. **C.O.I.**: Il demande le numéro à qui ? À Chantal.

Comment: Where did you find those?

Answer (score 8):

Traduction des deux phrases proposées :

> 1. He asks for Chantal's number →  Il demande le numéro *de* Chantal.

*numéro* est le Complément d'Objet Direct (*COD*), et, c’est le numéro *de* Chantal (comme cela pourrait être le nom *de* Chantal : Chantal X...).

***Mise en situation :***

> « Bonjour Pierre, quelle est le numéro *de* Chantal ? »

Où si l’on parle directement à Chantal :

> « Bonjour Chantal, quel est ton numéro ? »

- On demande -- quelque chose -- *de* quelqu'un : comme on demande le numéro *de* Chantal

  > Demander le téléphone *de* Pierre : On demande que Pierre prête *son* téléphone (on demande directement à Pierre ou par l’intermédiaire d’une tierce personne).

---

> 2. He asks Chantal for the number. →  Il demande le numéro *à* Chantal :

***Mise en situation :***
Correcte

> Je demande *à* Chantal le numéro de Pierre :
>   « Bonjour Chantal, quel est le numéro de Pierre ? »
>
> Je demande *à* Chantal quel est son numéro :
>   « Bonjour Chantal, quel est ton numéro ? »

- On demande -- quelque chose -- *à* quelqu'un
  On demande -- *à* quelqu'un -- quelque chose :

  > Demander le téléphone *à* Pierre (ou demander *à* Pierre le téléphone) : on s'adresse à Pierre pour qu'il nous donne *le* téléphone (celui que l'on vient de désigner).

*Incorrecte*

> « Bonjour Pierre, tu l’connaîs, toi (tautologie avec *tu*) le numéro *à* Chantal ? »

***Usage incorrect avec* à**

Comme @Relaxed le signal, quand on entend cette tournure malhabile, tout le monde comprend (surtout à l’aide du contexte, de l’intonation et de l’expression du locuteur) que le *à* est utilisé en tant que COD, au lieu d’être un Complément d’Objet Indirect (COI).

Ce n’est pas un problème en soi : qu'un traducteur laisse, en toute connaissance de cause : « Il demande son numéro à Chantal » pour traduire un dialogue enfantin ou très familier (s’il y a déjà une erreur de syntaxe dans la langue d’origine) est tout à fait acceptable,  qu'un non francophone parle ainsi n'a rien de choquant, il sera seulement repris par bon nombre de personnes et devra l’éviter dans sur son lieu de travail.

---

P.S. : @Random a fourni la réponse grammaticale dans son  commentaire, et @Relaxed a expliqué pourquoi l'on pouvait rencontrer *à* utilisé comme COD, point central de la question.

---

<sup>Réponse reformulée suite aux commentaires</sup>

Comment: +10 pour un cl-r plein d'inspiration dans ses exemples ! :)

Comment: Pour le 1, je dirais plutôt : "Bonjour Pierre, quel est le numéro de Chantal" ? En effet si la question est posée à Chantal, la phrase d'origine serait de préférence "Il demande son numéro à Chantal", même si ton explication reste correcte.

Comment: Selon moi "Il demande le numéro de Chantal" implique qu'on ne pose pas la question à Chantal. D'où ma proposition d'utiliser un exemple faisant intervenir une tierce personne.. mais je suis d'accord que ma formule avec "son" peut semer le trouble et ne règle pas la question "à" vs. "de"

Comment: Je pense que cette réponse passe complètement à côté de la question.

Comment: @Random Stéphane a motivé son commentaire sur Cosette : http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23885073#23885073 - Si vous pensez qu'il reste encore des améliorations à faire, je suis preneur.

Comment: +1 parce que la réponse est intéressante et couvre maintenant tous les problèmes soulevés mais je pense qu'il y a encore un léger problème d'interprétation. La question est très succincte mais il me semble qu'il s'agit de savoir pourquoi il y a deux traduction possibles de la phrase “le numéro à Chantal” et pas du tout de comment traduire les phrases anglaises proposées. J'ai l'impression que plusieurs contributeurs se sont laissés égarés par l'envie d'expliquer les règles de la grammaire française alors que c'est une approche purement descriptive qui était nécessaire ici.

Comment: @Relaxed - J'ai essayé de souligner ce point en complétant *Usage* avec "incorrect avec à"

Answer (score 4):

Among the two possibilities you mention, the only “proper” English translation of “Il demande le numéro à Chantal” in formal French is “He asks Chantal for the number”, where *Chantal* is the indirect object, hence “à Chantal”.

But “Il demande le numéro à Chantal” is actually somewhat common in current spoken French to express “He asks for Chantal's number”. In that case, *le numéro à Chantal* is the direct object and there is no indirect object.

Here, “X *à* X” is a possessive. It's not very common and might sound naive, childlike or perhaps colloquial (something you could hear from lower-class speakers probably) but I personally know people who use it systematically – i.e. not as a slip, a learner's mistake or anything but as the usual way to express this idea, that's just part of their dialect (in the East of France, if that matters).

Most educated speakers would consider this use incorrect (expecting “*de*” instead, as @cl-r explained) but you might encounter it and all native speakers would understand it, even if they disapprove. That might be why you found two translations for the sentence “Il demande le numéro à Chantal”.

Comment: C'est en effet un problème de l'Éducation nationale, et par conséquent de traduction. Qu'un traducteur laisse, en toute connaissance de cause  “Il demande le numéro à Chantal” pour traduire un dialogue enfantin ou très familier est tout à fait acceptable, mais il ne poserait pas la question sur ce site. Que tout le monde comprenne *à* à la place de *de* ne fait aucun doute, qu'un non francophone parle ainsi n'a rien de choquant, il sera seulement repris par bon nombre de personnes.

Comment: Sans être un puriste "Le numéro à chantal" pour parler du numéro **de** Chantal m'écorche les oreilles, d'autant que cela amène une ambiguïté. A part pour vouloir donner une tournure enfantine/naïve, je ne vois aucune raison de l'utiliser. (ah si, peut-être [la bite à dudule](http://bitu.org/chants/?chant=161), ou encore [La bite à Urbain](http://www.bedetheque.com/BD-Bite-a-Urbain-17075.html), à chaque fois avec le mot "bite"...

Comment: @LaurentS. N'est-ce pas exactement ce que je dis dans ma réponse ? Mais l'ambiguïté existe, en français, aujourd'hui, quoi qu'on en pense sur le plan prescriptif. La question ne porte d'ailleurs pas sur ce qu'il faut dire en français mais sur comment comprendre la phrase et sur l'existence de plusieurs traductions possibles en anglais.

Comment: Je ne dirais simplement pas "quite common", mais cela reste mon point de vue. Selon moi cela reste encore considéré par la plupart comme une erreur et donc quiconque fait un peu attention à la manière dont il s'exprime ne l'emploiera pas. "En vélo", par opposition, me paraît beaucoup plus commun, sans doute car moins ambigu.

Comment: @LaurentS. C'est probablement vrai, j'ai nuancé cette affirmation.

Comment: Merci, ca mérite donc un +1 :-)

Answer (score 2):

En français correct, on demande `quelquechose` **à** `quelqu'un`, donc la seconde traduction est théoriquement fausse et selon moi utilisée uniquement par des personnes n'ayant jamais fait attention à leur language ou dont le français n'est pas la langue maternelle (fréquentant de nombreux néerlandophones, je parle d'expérience au moins pour ceux-là).

> Il demande le numéro à Chantal / He asks Chantal for the number

C.O.D. = "le numéro"
C.O.I. = "Chantal"

On ne sait cependant pas de quel numéro il s'agit; Sans plus de précision, on suppose généralement qu'il s'agit d'un numéro de téléphone. Le contexte vient généralement éclaircir cela.

> Il demande le numéro de Chantal / He asks for Chantal's number

C.O.D. = "le numéro de Chantal"

On a un peu plus de précisions sur le numéro, sans savoir de quel numéro on parle exactement (encore une fois on suppose généralement un numéro de téléphone), on sait au moins à qui il appartient.

NOTE: Il n'est pas rare de rencontrer la tournure incorrecte "le truc **à** XXX" voulant en fait dire "le truc **de** XXX". Cela reste selon moi à proscrire car ambigu en fonction du contexte. La discussion sur cette question, qui n'offre justement aucun contexte, en est la preuve indéniable :-)

Comment: Je ne suis pas du tout d'accord avec cette façon de présenter les choses, si quelqu'un utilise effectivement “le numéro à Chantal” à la place du “numéro de Chantal”, alors “Chantal's number” est la seule traduction correcte, quoi qu'on pense de la tournure française. C'est en français qu'il y a un problème, pas en anglais.

Comment: Je ne pense pas d'ailleurs que cette tournure soit particulièrement courante chez les locuteurs dont le français n'est pas la langue maternelle. Elle est plutôt enfantine, ironique ou peut-être familière, au moins dans certaines régions, mais existe bel et bien et on doit donc la prendre en compte si on veut être complet. Car, encore une fois, pour cette question, la phrase française est le point de départ, ce qu'il faudrait dire selon tel ou tel point de vue n'est pas en cause, il s'agit de savoir comment la comprendre et la traduire.

Comment: @Relaxed > Un français incorrect résulte effectivement en une traduction incorrecte, mais je ne vois pas ce qu'il y a à discuter là-dedans... La phrase étant ici fournie sans aucun contexte, il me paraît normal de supposer qu'il s'agit d'un français correct. Je vais cependant tenir compte de ton commentaire et ajouter une remarque à ma réponse.

Comment: Il est normal de supposer qu'il s'agit de français, c'est tout. J'ai plus souvent entendu du français incorrect que du français correct. Et la limite est d'ailleurs floue.

Answer (score -1):

He asks for Chantal's number.

> **Il demande le numero de Chantal.**

He asks Chantal for the number.

> **Il demande le numero a Chantal.**

You were right. **Chantal** is the direct object(person), therefore, doesn't need **a**. However, there can be two sentence possible as stated above.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to say but **Il demande le numéro a Chantal* (without accent on the *a*) is in any case agrammatical. It seems you cannot type accents easily but in that case, it's quite important.

Comment: La deuxième phrase a une faute.